# Tumblr Blog: How to fix Submit Page & Ask Page box column count problem?

Tags: html, css, tumblr

I'm very new to HTML and CSS, and I've been having some trouble with my new Tumblr blog's custom layout.

Here's the blog link: https://wojakgallery.tumblr.com/

As you can see in the link above I'm using a grid with 6 columns for the posts.

The problem I see is in my Submit and Ask pages when viewing from a browser on PC (not mobile).

For example, as you can see in my Submit page, the submit box is too small for the content (making you unable to view it fully), the submit column box needs to be bigger.

However, when I edit the CSS column count, the ".grid section" below affects all posts on the whole blog, so if I change the column count to "column-count: 1;", all posts on the blog are displayed in 1 column.

```
.grid section {
        column-count: 6;
        break-inside: avoid;
        grid-gap: var(--spacing);
        margin-bottom:var(--spacing);
              }
```

How can I separate the Submit and Ask pages to have only 1 column count and centered, while keeping the rest of the other normal posts on the blog with "column-count: 6;"?

Is there a way to separate the HTML and CSS grid column codes for specific pages like Submit and Ask?

Below is the full HTML and CSS code of my Blog.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <!-- A custom theme built by eggdesign's theme builder (buildatheme.tumblr.com) -->
    <html> 
        <head>
        <!-- BEGIN: Powered by Supercounters.com -->
<center><script type="text/javascript" src="//widget.supercounters.com/ssl/online_i.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">sc_online_i(1684521,"ffffff","#283966");</script><br><noscript><a href="https://www.supercounters.com/">free online counter</a></noscript>
</center>
<!-- END: Powered by Supercounters.com -->
        
            <title>{Title}</title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale = 1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
            <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{Favicon}">
            <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" href="{RSS}">
            {block:Description}<meta name="description" content="{MetaDescription}" />{/block:Description}
            {block:Options}
            <meta name="color:background" content="#fff"/>
            <meta name="color:posts" content="#fff"/>
            <meta name="color:text" content="#000"/>
            <meta name="color:links" content="#000" />
            <meta name="color:tags" content="#000" />
            <meta name="color:sidebar links" content="{AccentColor}"/>
            <meta name="color:search background" content="#fff" />
            <meta name="color:search text" content="#000"/>
            <meta name="color:borders" content="#ddd"/>
            <meta name="text:border width" content="1px"/>
            <meta name="text:border radius" content="4px"/>
            <meta name="text:font size" content="16px" />
            <meta name="image:background" content=""/>
            <meta name="color:night mode accent" content="#fff" />
            <meta name="if:Remove background image in night mode" content=""/>
            <meta name="if:full background" content=""/>
             
            <meta name="select:Font" content="Helvetica" title="Helvetica" />
            <meta name="select:Font" content="Roboto" title="Roboto" />
            <meta name="select:Font" content="Favorit" title="Favorit" />
            <meta name="select:Font" content="Calluna" title="Calluna" />
            <meta name="select:Font" content="Fairwater" title="Fairwater" />
            <meta name="select:Font" content="Source Code Pro" title="Source Code Pro" />
            {/block:Options}

            {NewPostStyles}
            <script>
                const themed = localStorage.getItem('night-mode');
                if (themed === "enabled") {
                    sessionStorage.setItem('night-mode', 'enabled');
                    document.documentElement.classList.add('night-mode-theme');
                }
            </script>

            <script src="https://static.tumblr.com/svdghan/gFJrolu7g/daynight.js"></script>
             
             <style>
             @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700,900');

                * {
                    box-sizing: border-box;
                }
                :root {
                    --background-image:  url({image:background});
                    --background: {color:background};
                    --accent: {AccentColor};
                    --text: {color:text};
                    --borders: {color:borders};
                    --spacing: 1rem;
                    --border-width: {text:border width};
                    --border-radius: {text:border radius};
                    --posts: {color:posts};
                    --tags: {color:tags};
                    --links: {color:links};
                    --sidebar-links: {color:sidebar links};
                    --search-background: {color:search background};
                    --search-text: {color:search text};
                    --headerimage: url({HeaderImage}); 
                    --invert: invert(0);
                    --night-mode-accent: {color:night mode accent};
                     
                }
                
                .night-mode-theme {
                    --background: #000!important;
                    --accent: var(--night-mode-accent);
                    {block:ifRemoveBackgroundImageInNightMode}
                    --background-image: url('');
                    {/block:ifRemoveBackgroundImageInNightMode}
                    --text: white;
                    --posts: #222;
                    --invert: invert(1);
                    --links: var(--night-mode-accent);
                    --tags: var(--night-mode-accent);
                }
                
                body {
                    font-family: {select:Font}, sans-serif;
                    font-size: clamp(.92rem, {text:font size}, 20px);
                    margin: 0;
                    height: 100vh;
                    color: var(--text);
                    background: var(--background) var(--background-image) center center fixed;
                    {block:iffullbackground}
                    background-size: cover;
                    {/block:iffullbackground}}
                
                a {
                    color: var(--links);
                }
                
                header {
                    margin:var(--spacing) auto;
                    max-width:1100px;
                    padding:var(--spacing);
                    background:var(--posts);
                    border: var(--border-width) solid var(--borders);
                    border-radius:var(--border-radius);
                }
                
                article a {
                    text-decoration: none;
                }

                article a:hover {
                    text-decoration: underline;
                }

                article iframe, .tumblr_video_container {
                    max-width: 100%;
                }

                .blog-title {
                    font-family: {TitleFont};
                }

                main, .pagination {
                    display: flex;
                    flex-wrap: wrap;
                    align-items: flex-start;
                    justify-content: space-around;
                }

                main {
                    max-width:1100px;
                    margin:auto;
                }

                article, .pagination {
                    width: 100%;
                    position:relative;
                    max-width: 400px;
                    margin: calc(var(--spacing) * 4) auto;
                    border: var(--border-width) solid var(--borders);
                    border-radius: var(--border-radius);
                    background:var(--posts);
                }
                aside .pagination {
                    margin: var(--spacing) auto auto auto;
                }

                article img {
                    max-width: 100%;
                }

                .link-container {
                    padding: var(--spacing);
                    margin:var(--spacing);
                    border:var(--border-width) solid var(--borders);
                    border-radius: var(--border-radius);
                }

                .caption:empty, p:empty {
                    display:none;
                }

                .reblog-header a {
                    display: flex;
                    align-items:center;
                }

                .reblog-header img {
                    padding-right: .4rem;
                    max-height: 1.4rem;
                }
                .contained :is(header, footer, main) {
                    width: 100%;
                    max-width: 1000px;
                    margin: 1rem auto;
                    background: var(--background);
                    border: var(--border-width) solid var(--borders);
                }

                .contained header {
                    margin-bottom: 0;
                    padding: var(--spacing);
                }
                .contained main {
                    height: 70vh;
                    overflow: auto;
                    
                }

                .contained article, .contained .pagination {
                    max-width: 500px;
                }

                .grid main {
                    max-width: 98%;
                }

                .grid section {
                    column-count: 6;
                    break-inside: avoid;
                    grid-gap: var(--spacing);
                    margin-bottom:var(--spacing);
                }

                .grid article {
                    display: inline-block;
                    max-width: calc(100% - (var(--spacing) / 2));
                    margin: var(--spacing) 0;
                }

                .original-post, .reblog-header, .tags, .post-info, .pagination, .quote-container, .replies, .question {
                    padding: var(--spacing);
                }

                .reblog-content p, .reblog-content h2, .reblog-content h1 {
                    margin-left: var(--spacing);
                    margin-right: var(--spacing);
                }

                .quote-container, .replies, .question {
                    border: var(--border-width) solid var(--borders);
                    margin: var(--spacing);
                }

                .description, aside h2 {
                    padding: calc(var(--spacing) /2) 0;
                    margin: 0;
                }
                   #search-form input {
                    padding: calc(var(--spacing) / 2);
                    width:100%;
                    background:var(--search-background);
                    margin: calc(var(--spacing) /2) 0 0 0;
                    border:var(--border-width) solid var(--borders);
                    border-radius:var(--border-radius);
                    color:var(--search-text);
                 }
                ::placeholder {
                     color:var(--search-text);
                 }
                
                .post-info, .like-and-reblog, .contained {
                    display: flex;
                    flex-wrap: wrap;
                    align-items: center;
                    justify-content: space-between;
                }
                .pinned {
                    font-weight:bold;
                    color:var(--accent);
                }

                .pinned {
                    font-weight:bold;
                }
                .pinned-default {
                    padding:var(--spacing);
                }
                   
                .like-and-reblog .reblog_button, .like-and-reblog .like_button:not(.liked) {
                    filter: var(--invert);
                }
                 section {
                    width: 100%;
                 }
                
                    header {
                        width: 100%;
                    }
                
                .pages-container, .nav-container {
                    margin: calc(var(--spacing) /4) 0;
                }
                .pages-container a, .nav-container a, .pagination a, .tags a {
                    display: inline-block;
                    margin-right: .4rem;
                    color: var(--text);
                    text-decoration:none;
                }

                aside a {
                    color: var(--sidebar-links);
                }

                .tags a {
                    color: var(--tags);
                }

                .pages-container a {
                    font-weight:bold;
                    color:var(--accent);
                }

                .reblogs a, .caption a {
                    color:var(--accent);
                }

                .tumblr_audio_player {
                    width: 100%;
                }

                @media only screen and (max-width: 1100px) {
                    main, .contained main, section {
                        width: 100%;
                        height: auto;
                    }
                    
                    article {
                        max-width:90%;
                        margin: var(--spacing) auto;
                    }
                    
                    .grid section {
                        column-count: 1;
                    }

                }

                .screen-reader {
                    border: 0;
                    clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
                    clip-path: inset(50%);
                    height: 1px;
                    margin: -1px;
                    overflow: hidden;
                    padding: 0;
                    position: absolute;
                    width: 1px;
                    word-wrap: normal !important;
                }
                #daynight-toggle {
                    cursor:pointer;
                    background:;
                    position:fixed;
                    top:var(--spacing);
                    left:var(--spacing);
                    z-index:2;
                    height:2rem;
                    width:2rem;
                    border-radius:50%;
                    background:white;
                    display:flex;
                    border:var(--border-width) solid var(--borders);
                    flex-wrap:wrap;
                    justify-content:center;
                    align-items:center;
                }
                
                #daynight-toggle:before {
                    content:'☀';
                }
                
                #daynight-toggle.night-mode-toggle:before {
                  content:'';
                  width:1rem;
                  height:1rem;
                  transform:translate(-.32rem, -.32rem);
                  border-radius: 50%;
                  box-shadow: .32rem .32rem 0 0 black;
                }
                
                {CustomCSS}
            </style>
        </head>
        <body class="grid {block:homepage}home{/block:homepage}{block:tagpage}tag{/block:tagpage}{block:searchpage}search{/block:searchpage}{block:submitpage}submit-{/block:submitpage}{block:AskPage}ask{/block:AskPage}-page">
           
           <!-- Day/Night Toggle start <button id="daynight-toggle"><span class="screen-reader">toggle day and night mode</span></button> End -->  
           
           <header>  {block:ShowTitle}
            
           <a style="text-decoration: none; color:#0c1630;" href="https://wojakgallery.tumblr.com/"><h2 class="blog-title">{Title}</h2></a> 
            
            {/block:ShowTitle}
            <div class="description">{Description}</div>
                    <div class="nav-container">
                    <a href="https://wojakgallery.tumblr.com/"><b>[Home]</b></a>
                        <a href="https://wojakgallery.tumblr.com/random"><b>[Random Post]</b></a>
                        {block:askenabled}
                            <a href="/ask"><b>[Ask]</b></a>
                        {/block:askenabled}
                        {block:submissionsenabled}
                            <a href="/submit"><b>[Submit]</b></a>
                        {/block:submissionsenabled}
                        <a href="/archive"><b>[Archive]</b></a>
                    </div> 
                      {block:HasPages}
                        <div class="pages-container">
                            {block:Pages}
                                <a href="{URL}">{Label}</a>
                            {/block:Pages}
                            </div>
                        {/block:HasPages}
                        <form action="/search" method="get" id="search-form">
                            <input type="text" name="q" class="query" value="" placeholder=" Search Tags (type & hit enter)">
                        </form></header>
                 
            <main>
                <section>
                
                    {block:SearchPage}
                        <article>
                            <div class="reblogs">{lang:Found SearchResultCount results for SearchQuery}
                                <div class="Sorry" style="margin-left:5px;">
                                {block:NoSearchResults}
    <p>Sorry, no listings are tagged with "{SearchQuery}."</p>
{/block:NoSearchResults}
</div>                        
 </div>
 </article>                                                  
                    {/block:SearchPage}
                    
                    {block:TagPage}
                        <article>
                            <div class="reblogs">{lang:Showing TagResultCount posts tagged Tag}</div>
                        </article>
                    {/block:TagPage}
                    {block:DayPage}
                        <article>
                            <div class="reblogs">{lang:Viewing everything posted on Month DayOfMonth Year}</div>
                        </article>
                    {/block:DayPage}
                    {block:Posts}
                    <!-- {block:NoRebloggedFrom}
                    
                    {block:RebloggedFrom}{ReblogParentName}{/block:RebloggedFrom}
                    {/block:NoRebloggedFrom} -->
                    {block:ContentSource}<!-- {SourceURL}
                    {block:SourceLogo}<img src="{BlackLogoURL}"width="{LogoWidth}" height="{LogoHeight}" alt="{SourceTitle}" />{/block:SourceLogo}
                    {block:NoSourceLogo}{SourceLink}{/block:NoSourceLogo} -->
                    {/block:ContentSource} 
                    <article id="post-{PostID}">
                        {block:PinnedPostLabel}<div class="pinned pinned-default"><i></i>{PinnedPostLabel}</div>{/block:PinnedPostLabel}
                         
                                
                                {block:RebloggedFrom}
                                    <div class="reblog-header">
                                        <a href="{permalink}" {block:isdeactivated}class="inactive"{/block:isdeactivated}>
                                        <img src={ReblogRootPortraitURL-64} alt="{ReblogRootName}">  {ReblogRootName}
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                {/block:RebloggedFrom}
                                {block:Photo}
                                    <img src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}" alt="{photoalt}" class="photos">
                                {/block:Photo}

                                {block:Photoset}
                                    {Photoset}
                                {/block:Photoset}
                                    
                                {block:Panorama}
                                    <img src="{photourl-panorama}" alt="{photoalt}">
                                {/block:Panorama}
                                        
                                {block:Quote}
                                
                                    <div class="quote-container">
    
                                        <div class="quote">
                                            "{Quote}"
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="source">
                                            -{Source}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    
                                    
                                {/block:Quote}
                                          
                                {block:Chat}
                                    <ul class="chat">
                                        {block:Lines}
                                            <li>
                                                {block:Label}{Label}{/block:Label} 
                                                {Line}
                                            </li>
                                        {/block:Lines}
                                    </ul>
                                {/block:Chat}

                                {block:link}
                                    <div class="link-container">
                                        <a href="{URL}">
                                            {Name}
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                {/block:link}
                                              
                                {block:Video}
                                    {Video-700}
                                {/block:Video}
                                    
                                {block:Audio}
                                    {audioembed}
                                {/block:Audio}
         
                                {block:Answer}
                                    <div class="question">
                                        {Asker}: {Question}
                                    </div>
                                    {block:Answerer}
                                    <div class="replies">
                                        {Answerer}: {Answer}
                                    </div>
                                    {/block:Answerer}
                                {block:NotReblog}
                                    <div class="replies">
                                        {Replies}
                                    </div>
                                {/block:NotReblog}
                                {/block:Answer}
                                <!-- captions  -->
                                <div class="caption {block:notreblog} original-post {/block:notreblog}">
                                    {block:Text}
                                    
                                        {block:Title}<h2>{Title}</h2>{/block:Title}
                                     
                                    {/block:Text}
                                    <hr>
                                    {block:notreblog}
                                    {block:caption}{Caption}{/block:caption}
                                    {block:Text}{body}{/block:Text}
                                    {/block:notreblog}
                                    {block:Rebloggedfrom}
                                        {block:Reblogs}
                                        <div class="reblogs">
                                        {block:IsNotOriginalEntry} 
                                            <div class="reblog-header">
                                                <a href="{permalink}" {block:isdeactivated}class="inactive"{/block:isdeactivated}>
                                                      <img src={PortraitURL-64} alt="{username}">  {username}
                                                    </a>
                                            </div>
                                        {/block:IsNotOriginalEntry} 
                                            <div class="reblog-content">
                                                {Body}
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        {/block:Reblogs}
                                    {/block:RebloggedFrom}
                             
                             <hr>  
                             <div class="container">
                             
                             <div class="topleft">
                             {LikeButton}</div>
                             <div class="topright">
                             {ReblogButton}</div>
                                 
                             </div>   
                             
                                </div>
                                
                                
                                <!–– START DATE POSTED AND TAGS ––>
                                
                                
                                 {block:Date}<div class="post-info">
                                <div class="note-info">
                                    <a href="{Permalink}">Posted <a href="/day/{year}/{MonthNumberWithZero}/{DayOfMonth}">{TimeAgo}</a> with <a href="{Permalink}"> {NoteCountwithLabel}</a></div>
                                
                                </div>{/block:Date}  
                                
                                
                            {block:PermalinkPage}    
                            {block:Hastags}
                            <div class="tags">
                                {block:Tags}
                                <a href="{TagURL}">#{Tag}</a>
                                {/block:Tags}
                            </div>
                        {/block:Hastags}
                        {/block:PermalinkPage}
                        
                        
                        <!–– END DATE POSTED AND TAGS ––>
                                
                             
                        {PostNotes}
                    </article>
                    {/block:Posts}
                     
                {block:Pagination}
                <div class="pagination flex centered">
                    {block:previouspage}
                    <a href="{previouspage}">Prev</a>
                    {/block:previouspage}
                        {block:JumpPagination length="5"}
                            {block:CurrentPage}
                            <span class="current-page">
                                {PageNumber}
                            </span>
                            {/block:CurrentPage}
                            {block:JumpPage}
                            <a href="{URL}">
                                {PageNumber}
                            </a>
                            {/block:JumpPage}
                        {/block:JumpPagination}
                    {block:nextpage}
                    <a href="{nextpage}">Next</a>
                    {/block:nextpage}
                </div>
                {/block:Pagination}
                 </section></main>
            </body>
        </html>
```

Extra Custom CSS:

```
.blog-title {
    font-family: {TitleFont};
    font-size: 30px;
                }

.pages-container, .nav-container {
                    margin: calc(var(--spacing) /1) 0;
                    
                }
 
 .pages-container a {
        background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #290c9d 5%, #290c9d 100%);
    background-color:#290c9d;
    border-radius:5px;
    border:1px solid #4e6096;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:Helvetica;
    font-size:17px;
    padding:6px; 18px; 
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 6px #283966;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    margin-top:4px;

background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #476e9e 5%, #7892c2 100%);
    background-color:#476e9e;
    position:relative;
    margin-right:0px;
    
                }
             
             
              /* LIKE BUTTON AND REBLOG BUTTON START */ 
             
             .container {
  position: relative;
}   
         
         
         .topleft {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 0px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

 .topright {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 25px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

   /* LIKE BUTTON AND REBLOG BUTTON END */
```

Comment: I've done this many times using a little snippet of JavaScript. See my second part of an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70473354/1238244

Comment: If that doesn't make sense or you cannot get it to work I'll post something here later today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I checked your tumblr blog and it seems as though classes are already being passed to the submit and ask pages, so you can target them through css.

This is how I would do it

```
<style>
/* use this css which is already in the theme to target standard index, post pages etc. */
.grid section {
    column-count: 6;
    break-inside: avoid;
    grid-gap: var(--spacing);
    margin-bottom: var(--spacing);
}

/* extend the css for ask/submit pages */
body.submit--page .grid section,
body.ask-page .grid section {
    column-count: unset // reset the column-count property
    grid-gap: 0;
    // add another styles here you only want to target on these pages
}
</style>
```

This should do everything you need, but only covers those two pages.

If you want a more comprehensive solution to add a class to any page (and therefore be able to target the css specifically) let me know. But it is covered in the other answer I linked to.

I am not sure why `submit--page` has a double dash and `ask-page` only one, but at least each page has a unique identifier.

**EDIT**

Apologies, I just noticed again in your theme, that the `grid` class is also applied to the body. Hence `body.submit--page .grid section` does not exist as grid is not a child of the body, it is the same element.

Change the selectors to

```
body.submit--page section,
body.ask-page section {
    // styles...
```

**EDIT 2**

To handle desktop/mobile you need to update media queries.

Find this code in your theme  (this is for mobile)

```
media only screen and (max-width: 1100px)
.grid section {
    column-count: 1;
}
```

If mobile is always a single column then this is fine.

For desktop and mobile this should cover it (note you are now entering specifity issues)

```
/* desktop */
body.submit--page section,
body.ask-page section {
    column-count: 3 // add your column count for desktop here
    grid-gap: 0;
}

/* mobile/tablet */
media only screen and (max-width: 1100px)
    body.submit--page section,
    body.ask-page section {
        column-count: 1; // reset columns to 1 for mobile
}
```

Comment: I added the following below to the CSS, but nothing changed. 
Any idea if there's something I'm missing?

/* extend the css for ask/submit pages */
body.submit--page .grid section,
body.ask-page .grid section {
    column-count: 1;
    grid-gap: 0;
}

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I will update my answer.

Comment: That worked. TY. One last thing, when I add the code from your edit, it also affects mobile. I need the mobile view to be 1 column and the PC view to be 3 columns. Any idea how I can do that?

Comment: @GFB I have added a css media query (there is one in your template already, you should pass styles for mobile to this css query)

Comment: Ok, so here's the code I'm using for mobile, but on mobile it continues to show in 3 columns instead of 1 (which I want for mobile), seems it's still pushing the desktop code which is set to 3 columns.

@media only screen and (max-width: 1100px) 
{main, .contained main, section {width: 100%; height: auto;}

article {max-width:90%; margin: var(--spacing) auto;}

.grid section {column-count: 1;}

body.submit--page section,
body.ask-page section {
column-count: 1; 
grid-gap: 0;}
}

Comment: @GFB can you dump the current entire template into pastebin for me and post the url here? https://pastebin.com/ There are some other selectors in your css, but then  I should be able to fix everything in one go.

Comment: Here: https://pastebin.com/ACXe0tBj

Comment: Can you try this? https://pastebin.com/HFbY4ZRP I just removed one small block of selectors. I tried testing it on a tumblr here: https://hoffman-test.tumblr.com/submit (and check the home page https://hoffman-test.tumblr.com) there is some odd formatting issue on in the index page, might be some other config in the code. Hopefully this will be OK on your tumblr. Obviously I would keep a copy of the existing theme, but lucky Tumblr has a built in function https://www.tumblr.com/themes/recover

Comment: TYSM! The Submit and Ask are both ok now in desktop and mobile with your pastebin code.

Comment: Glad we got there in the end.